# KineticJS - Slow performance when animating tile opacity [Example]

Tags: javascript, canvas, coffeescript, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I'm having a problem with a grid of Rect shapes.

Grid is 120 by 60.

JSFiddle example here http://jsfiddle.net/5MfYR/

---

Here is the equivalent in CoffeeScript code:

```
window.size = {
    width: $(window).width()
    height: $(window).height()
}

window.grid = {
    size: {
        x: 40*3
        y: 20*3
    }
    tiles: []
}

window.stage = new Kinetic.Stage {
    container: "container"
    width: window.size.width - 10
    height: window.size.height - 10
}

window.gridLayer = new Kinetic.Layer {

}
window.stage.add window.gridLayer

createSquares = ()->
    console.log "CREATING TILES"

    tileSize = {
        width: parseFloat(window.size.width) / window.grid.size.x
        height: parseFloat(window.size.height) / window.grid.size.y
    }


    for ix in [0..window.grid.size.x]
        for iy in [0..window.grid.size.y]

            tile = new Kinetic.Rect {
                x: ix*tileSize.width
                y: iy*tileSize.height
                width: tileSize.width
                height: tileSize.height

                fill: "#ff3300"
                stroke: "#ff3300"
            }

            window.grid.tiles.push tile

            window.gridLayer.add tile

    window.gridLayer.draw()
    return

createSquares()

refreshTiles = ()->
    for tile in window.grid.tiles
        tile.setOpacity Math.random()
    window.gridLayer.draw()

setInterval ()->
    stats.begin()
    refreshTiles()
    stats.end()
, 100
```

---

Any idea what the bottleneck is?

Any alternative way to animate tile opacity?

Comment: If you did this in jsbin instead of jsfiddle it'd be a little easier to profile with the Chrome developer tools. The result stuff is stuck inside an iframe in jsfiddle.

Comment: Also, you're trying to do 72000 DOM updates per second. I suspect that the rendering engine is the bottleneck.

Comment: Thanks @Pointy. I guess there is no way to increase performance and obtain the same result?

Comment: Some ways change "draw" to "drawScene", remove "stroke" config. This will 4x increase perfomance.

Comment: offtopic: Pointy, this is not DOM, it is canvas - it is important. And to see jsfiddle as you want just add /show to url: http://jsfiddle.net/5MfYR/show/